# Original Lookup Field Value Not Retained

Tags: trigger, before-trigger

I have an apex trigger that is supposed to capture a field's original value, no matter you update it many times. The value should still be the original one.

For example:

```
Lookup Field: Value1
Original Lookup Value: Value1
```

Say I updated the `Lookup Field` into Value2, the `Original Lookup Value` field must still be Value1.

**Expected result for each scenario:**

**Original:**

Lookup Field: Value1

Original Lookup Value: Value1

**1st Edit:**

Lookup Field: Value2

Original Lookup Value: Value1

**2nd Edit:**

Lookup Field: Value3

Original Lookup Value: Value1

But every time I update the lookup field value, the original lookup value does not retain. In fact, it gets the previous value of a field every time it's edited.

**Apex Trigger:**

```
trigger MyTrigger on Object__c (before update) {

    for(Object__c o : Trigger.new) {

        if(o.Lookup_Field__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(o.Id).Lookup_Field__c) {

            o.Original_Lookup_Value__c = Trigger.oldMap.get(o.Id).Lookup_Field__c;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide more examples in terms of values of the result that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: My apologies, pasted it wrong. But modified my code.

Comment: Not it should be working

Comment: I've added sample scenarios with expected results on my post

Comment: My code works, but not as what I am expecting. Every time I edit the record, the field holding the original value of the lookup field changes.

Comment: I guess that you need to set Original_Lookup_Value__c into  old Lookup_Field__c if and only if  Original_Lookup_Value__c is null. Otherwise, you already have your original value

Comment: @kurunve thanks it is working now. I just added another criteria that check the nullity of the `Original_Lookup_Value__c` field.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you even need to write this trigger? Or you can write only one line in your trigger for loop code.

```
 o.Original_Lookup_Value__c = Trigger.oldMap.get(o.Id).Original_Lookup_Value__c;
```

This line will always keep the original value in your field.